# Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2 KafkaHealthIndicator, Actuator {“status”:“DOWN”}

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-kafka

I ported my application from `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6` to `Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2` and ran into the issue with `KafkaHealthIndicator` that thinks right now, that my Kafka status is `DOWN`.

```
  kafka":{
     "status":"DOWN",
     "details":{
        "clusterId":"wpAKGc_DQBWy9YfPTLNctQ",
        "brokerId":"0",
        "nodes":1
     }
  }
```

`org.springframework.boot.actuate.kafka.KafkaHealthIndicator` uses the following logic in order to determine the status:

```
Status status = nodes >= replicationFactor ? Status.UP : Status.DOWN;
```

where replication factor is retrieved by the following property: `transaction.state.log.replication.factor`

I have added the following properties to my Kafka `server.properties`:

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
```

but it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Right now, I use the temporal solution with disabling healthcheck for Kafka:

```
management.health.kafka.enabled=false
```

but I don't like it and I want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me...

```
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
```

with

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48965775Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48965775Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaHealthIndicator health) {
        return args -> {
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(health.health());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
UP {clusterId=ZR4GdILXSFSIGI1wDiKNLg, brokerId=0, nodes=1}
```

Did you restart the broker after changing the properties?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I restarted the broker. Also, under the Windows with the following Kafka Docker image - https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/ with tag 1.0.0 everything is also working fine. I have this issue under my Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1

Comment: Also, I didn't have such issue under Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6

Comment: The health indicator is new. Yes, I tested with 1.0.0 on MacOS; what version is the Debian image using?  We have been discussing this issue on the [kafka health indicator PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/11515#issuecomment-368095542) if you want to follow along.

Comment: I do not use Docker there, Kafka is installed directly into the host OS - `Linux version 4.9.0-6-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u2 (2018-02-21)`

Comment: But which Kafka version? It makes no sense to me for the OS to make a difference in how Kafka sets its properties.

Comment: I'm not the person who is installed the Kafka there, so I may be wrong but based on the versions of the file names - this is Kafka 1.0.0

Comment: for example kafka_2.11-1.0.0.jar

Comment: Strange. Maybe it's getting the properties someplace else. A debugger in the health indicator would show you what the broker is returning.